# It's inside m​e, too

Tags: riddle, word

When it has been locked in, it's power is itself,

All visitors to dock 80 bring this in itself,

It is by far most abundant,

And it appears when you go after what remains ​

Answer (score 14):

Is it

> **rest?**

In a music list, it's power is itself,

> a [rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rest_(music)) in paper music ("music list") results in a short rest for the musician.

All visitors to dock 80 bring this in itself,
It is by far most abundant,

> [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) is built on top of HTTP, which has TCP port 80 [assigned to it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers). It seems to be the most popular API type nowadays. (There are plenty of other visitors to that particular "dock" too, though, so maybe my guess is off.)

And it appears when you go after what remains ​

> "what remains" = "the rest"

Title: "It's inside m​e, too"

> [RE1-silencing Transcription Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RE1-silencing_transcription_factor) is an unwieldy name for the REST protein, which is encoded by a gene with the same name.

Comment: Not the quite right answer. Hint: rot13(Orpnhfr bs bar bs gur yvarf, V pbafvqrerq gnttvat guvf dhrfgvba zngurzngvpf)

Comment: This does seem like an entirely valid answer that was unintended. If that is the case, you'll (@Jazck) have to edit your question to make sure that the true answer and *only* the true answer will fit.

Comment: Is that the rule? Alright, I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could be a

> Header (of a packet)

*When it has been locked in, it's power is itself,*

> ‘Locked in’ in this context could mean securely storing a data packet. Or, encrypting a data packet with an encapsulated security payload which is referenced by another header.

*All visitors to dock 80 bring this in itself,*

> The data packets to port 80 (which is primarily for HTTP) are of no exception, they have headers too.

*It is by far most abundant,*

> Nearly every data packet comes with a header

*And it appears when you go after what remains*

> What remains is the payload and you refer the header for the payload

The title: *It’s inside me, too*

> Yes, if you are viewing this online, you are technically translating data from packets which contain headers too.